# Android: Problems With ListView (Updating/Passing Values Into It From Another Activity Using Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have an activity and upon a certain condition, it will pass an integer value to the activity that contains the ListView. However, I am running into several problems:

1. There is an initial value of 0 and when the activity is performed and the condition is met another 0 gets passed in, instead of the actual value.
2. The ListView is reset every time it is run from the main activity. I would like it to keep the results from previous runs (until a user hits a reset button on the ListView activity itself).

**EDIT
 3. I have noticed behavior that I did not notice before and that is that every time the ListView activity is opened from the main activity, another 0 is added to the ListView.

Here is the relevant code -

Activity Passing Value to Activity Containing ListView:

```
if(condition) {
    textview.setText("String1");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("numCounter", numCounter);
}
```

Activity with ListView:

```
ListView numListView;
ArrayAdapter<Integer> listAdapter; 

static ArrayList<Integer> numArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int intentNum = intent.getIntExtra("numCounter", 0);
    addNumArrayList(intentNum);

    numListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.numberListView);

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.listview_row, numArrayList);

    numListView.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
}

// Keep ArrayList to size of 10, while keeping it sorted 
// (displaying only the 10 lowest)

public static void addNumArrayList(int val) {
    numArrayList.add(val);
    Collections.sort(numArrayList);
    if(numArrayList.size() > 10) {
        for(int i = 10; i < numArrayList.size(); i++) {
            numArrayList.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I basically would like it so that only the other activity or activities can alter it, except when the reset button is hit on the ListView activity itself (simply opening the activity from the main activity should do nothing).

How do I fix it?

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Try to provide a better example of the activity flow and what happens. Also, keep in mind that with the current code you'll add `0` or another int value every time the list activity is called.

Comment: @Luksprog Ok let's say I want to keep track of the number of times the user clicks a button (that's the "numCounter") I want pass that value to another activity that has the ListView and basically keep a table (list) of the number of clicks the user does at each session. The table will be sorted lowest to highest and I am only keeping the ten lowest. Currently as it sits, the value is not being passed in from the intent from the other activity. Every time I view the the List Activity from the main activity another 0 is passed in, which I do not want to happen.

Comment: @Luksprog I am asking how I fix it and get the functionality I want and not to simply restate what I have already discovered and pointed out in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below condition for addnumArrayList

```
Bundle mBundle = intent.getExtras();
if(mBundle != null && mBundle.containsKey(¨numCounter¨)){
    int intentNum = intent.getIntExtra("numCounter", 0);
    addNumArrayList(intentNum);
}
```

You are getting the default value of 0 even if the key is not present. So do check if the key is present

As far as the listView getting reset, you should store values in a file rather than in a static variable, the values will be reset if the process is killed.

Edit: Try this

```
   int intentNum = intent.getIntExtra("numCounter", -1); // -1 or any number that you do not pass
   if(intentNum != -1)
    addNumArrayList(intentNum);
```

Comment: So now it is blank and even after going through the other activity and then pulling up the List View it is still blank. Is this to be expected?

Comment: i am not sure what you are doing in the other activity. are you launching the listActivity and passing the extra

Comment: No that is all the code I have for it. I am simply creating a new Intent and passing the value to the ListView.

Comment: You have written **upon a certain condition, it will pass an integer value to the activity** what is this condition? I guess this condition is never being met. Where are you adding the extra?

Comment: The condition is being met because the TextView is being printed to the screen, so that's not the issue. I am new to the ListView/keeping values so they do not get erased. It is just a feature that I wanted to add that way the user can use it for reference every time the user uses the app.

Comment: Still blank. After running the activity from the main activity, I hit the back button and then open up the ListView activity from the main activity and it is still blank.

Comment: Do you have any more suggestions? I would like to get this feature implemented and working.

Comment: i am still confused, is the activity launched any time with extra numCounter , i dont think you are launching it right with this extra

Comment: No it is not. I simply want to pass the value to the ListView and have it added. That way, if the user does not want to look at the ListView at the time, the user can do so next time the app is launched or whatever.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21187/discussion-between-nandeesh-and-lord-sneed)

Comment: You managed to fix the initial 0 problem and I guess I need to inquire about internal data storage in another question so I will accept your answer, unless someone else manages to solve all of the problems.